# Is there a parameter for default height for widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

I am trying to implement my own "expandable panel" in Flutter, basically there are questions and their answers, all having different length naturally. What i want to do is to display the question in a container first, and when user clicks the container i want to expand the second container's height, which has the answer text, from 0 to ***the height value it's answer requires***

```
double _theHeight = 0;

Column(
   children: [
      Container(
         child:Inkwell(
            onTap: () {setState({_theHeight = ????})},
            child: Text(theQuestion)
         )
      ),
      Container(
         height = _theHeight,
         child: Text(theAnswer),
      ),
   ]
)
```

In such example, i tried to give _theHeight variable a constant value like 200 but as different answers have different lengths, this causes an overflow or too much unnecessary place.

Is there a default value for height such that the parent widget will only cover the space it's child requires? So can i type something like:

```
_theHeight = Container.default.height;
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply wrap the answer inside the container.
No need to give specific height. You can just check if the widget is expanded or not

**Example:**

```html
bool isExpanded = false;

Column(
   children: [
      Container(
         child:Inkwell(
            onTap: () {setState({isExpanded = !isExpanded})},
            child: Text(theQuestion)
         )
      ),
      if(isExpanded)
        Container(
           child: Text(theAnswer),
        ),
   ]
)
```

For animated container, you could use AnimatedSize something like

```html
AnimatedSize(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    child: isExpanded ? Container() : const Text(theAnswer),
),
```

Comment: Okay this works, but what if i want to add a sliding animation to answer container? If i use AnimatedContainer with a constant height value, it gives a beautiful sliding animation, but with this solution, the second container immediately appears on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still, the container suddenly appears on the screen without any animation.

Comment: try suing AnimatedSize for the animation. Updated answer

Comment: Now the animation works too, thanks again.